# Se me duplica el Range Slider (Rails)

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, slider

tengo un problema que no se si es el navegador o algo que tengo en el código, me explico:

en mi pagina tengo un RangeSlider que funciona de maravilla, pero cuando me voy a otro lado de la pagina (a otra sección) y regreso a donde esta el RangeSlider con el atras del navegador, este RangeSlider se me duplica tantas veces yo haga este procedimiento, comparto imagenes y el codigo a ver si es algo que tengo malo. Gracias de antemano.

RangeSlider Bien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

RangeSilder Duplicado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo que utilizo:

```js
function setRangeSlider(text) {
  $('.input-range').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).attr('data-slider-value');
    var separator = value.indexOf(',');

    if (separator !== -1) {
      value = value.split(',');
      value.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
        arr[i] = parseFloat(item);
      });
    } else {
      value = parseFloat(value);
    }

    $(this).slider({
      formatter: function(value) {
        return value;
      },

      min: parseFloat($(this).attr('data-slider-min')),
      max: parseFloat($(this).attr('data-slider-max')),
      range: $(this).attr('data-slider-range'),
      value: value
    });
  });

  $('.input-range').on('slide', function(slideEvt) {
    slideEvt.value[0] == '0' ? $('#min').text(text) : $('#min').text('$' + slideEvt.value[0]);
    slideEvt.value[1] == $('.input-range').attr('data-slider-max') ? $('#max').text('$' + slideEvt.value[1] + '+') : $('#max').text('$' + slideEvt.value[1]);
  })
}

function setByPrice(event, name) {
  var min = event.value[0];
  var max = event.value[1] == $('.input-range').attr('data-slider-max') ? 'Infinity' : event.value[1];

  $.ajax({
    url: 'ruta.js',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
      min: min,
      max: max
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center m-2">
  <div id="by-price-slider" class="slider-wrapper slider-primary slider-strips slider-ghost">
    <input class="input-range" type="text" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="1, 5" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="51" data-slider-range="true" data-slider-tooltip_split="true"/>
    <div id="post-range" class="top-posts-title m-2">
      <span id="min"></span> - <span id="max"></span>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
    
<script>
  $(function() {
    setRangeSlider('<%= t('helpers.posts.free')%>');

    $('.input-range').on('slideStop', function(event){
      setByPrice(event,'ruta');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Disculpen que no puedo ponerle el ejemplo en vivo, como la librería de bootstrap-slider.js esta instalada con la gema en rails no se como agregarla aqui al ejemplo para que lo puedan ver.

asi me sale en el inspector del navegador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: porque utilizas each?? cuantos range slider son???

Comment: es solo un range slider, sera por el each, que se me duplica cada vez que hago voy a un lugar y despues voy para atras?

Comment: si solo tienes 1 elemento no es necesario un each!

Comment: lo quite e igual me sigue duplicando n veces el range slider

Comment: podrias agregar el resultado en consola cuando se duplica dando click derecho inpeccionar~

Comment: listo, la agregue en la publicacion

Comment: logre evitar la duplicacion del elemento con if ($('#by-price-slider > .slider').length > 0) pero ahora necesito colocar los valores del rango que seleccione cuando regreso de nuevo a la vista.